# Vbox layout issue in a tab panel

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm having an issue with a `vbox` layout so I created a simple example
that illustrates the problem, which is getting my `vbox` layout to `fit`
the height of the screen.

On the `hbox` screen, the view looks as expected.

[image]

---

However, when I simply change `hbox` to `vbox` all the text overlays in the top left corner.

[image]

---

All the code is given below and it's on [Sencha Fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#cxuMl)

---

> app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'SenchaFiddle',

    views: ['MainView', 'HboxView', 'VboxView'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SenchaFiddle.view.MainView'));

    }
});
```

---

> MainView.js

```
Ext.define("SenchaFiddle.view.MainView", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            title: 'hbox',
            iconCls: 'action',

            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Hbox'
            }, {
                xtype: 'hbox-view'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'vbox',
            iconCls: 'action',
            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Vbox'
            }, {
                xtype: 'vbox-view'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

---

> HboxView.js

```
Ext.define("SenchaFiddle.view.HboxView", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'hbox-view',
    config: {
        style: 'background-color: #0f0',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'baz',
            style: 'background-color: #ff0',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'foo',
            style: 'background-color: #f00',
            flex: 2
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'bar',
            style: 'background-color: #fff',
            flex: 3
        }]
    }
});
```

---

> VboxView.js

```
Ext.define("SenchaFiddle.view.VboxView", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'vbox-view',
    config: {
        style: 'background-color: #0f0',
        layout: 'vbox',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'baz',
            style: 'background-color: #ff0',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'foo',
            style: 'background-color: #f00',
            flex: 2
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'bar',
            style: 'background-color: #fff',
            flex: 3
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Sencha are you using? What CSS file are you using ?

Comment: 2.0.1 is used on SenchaFiddle.  I think they include the CSS. http://www.senchafiddle.com/#cxuMl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in MainView.js structure.
Your vbox wrapper container has no layout:

```
{
  title: 'vbox',
  iconCls: 'action',
  layout: card, // or fit, etc. :)
  items: [
    {
      docked: 'top',
      xtype: 'titlebar',
      title: 'Vbox'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'vbox-view'
    }
  ]
},
```

But it's not very good code.
Better to add titlebar and some configs to VBoxView and HboxView definition:

```
 Ext.define("SenchaFiddle.view.VboxView", {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        xtype: 'vbox-view',
        config: {
            style: 'background-color: #0f0',
            layout: 'vbox',
            title: 'Vbox', // this is better place for title and iconCls :)
            iconCls: 'action',
            items: [
                // title bar is here :) 
                {
                   type: 'titlebar',
                   docked: 'top',
                   title: 'Navigation',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'baz',
                    style: 'background-color: #ff0',
                    flex: 1
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'foo',
                    style: 'background-color: #f00',
                    flex: 2
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',                
                    html: 'bar',
                    style: 'background-color: #fff',
                    flex: 3
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

And in MainView.js

```
Ext.define("SenchaFiddle.view.MainView", {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
  // ...    
  config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    items: [
      {xtype: 'hbox-view'}, // very nice code :)
      {xtype: 'vbox-view'},
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: There's an auto layout by default?  I added the 'fit' layout and created a new SenchaFiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#MNi3i

Comment: And yes, it's cleaner to break it out.  I generated the basic code with Sencha's CLI tools.  They should probably do it this way, but every beginner who starts with their tutorials/cmd will get this code. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started