# vbox layout working in Firefox but not in Google Chrome after adding a layout to the container element

Tags: javascript, layout, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to create a screen with Sencha Touch 2 with the following structure:
[image]

Where the red main square is a Panel,, the blue square is a container and the geen squares should be two items with HTML content in them.

Below is the code I use in the Main.js file

```
Ext.define('EventApp.view.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    id : 'mainView',
    xtype : 'main',
    requires : [ 'Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video' ],
    config : {
        tabBarPosition : 'bottom',

        items : [ {
            title : 'Home',
            iconCls : 'home',

            items : [ {
                docked : 'top',
                xtype : 'titlebar',
                title : 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
            }, {
                xtype : 'eventsCarrousel'
            } ],
        }, 

        {
            title : 'Events',
            iconCls : 'time',
            id : 'eventsButton',

            items : [ {
                docked : 'top',
                xtype : 'titlebar',
                title : 'Events'
            }, {
                xtype : 'eventList',
            } ]
        } 
        ]
    }
});
```

and in the view named eventsCarrousel.js

```
Ext.define('EventApp.view.eventsCarrousel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'eventsCarrousel',
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items : [{
            flex: 1,
            html : "This is the sample top pannel." ,
            style : 'background-color: #5E99CC;'
        }, {
            flex: 1,
            html : "Second pannel.",
            style : 'background-color: #4D99CC;'
        }]
    }
});
```

What I get out of this code is the following output:
[image: Output obtained with code above]

Here are my problems (which I have circled in red)

1. In Google Chrome the title text of the main panel is not displaying although it does display if I use Netscape.
2. The items do not seem to be arranged using the vbox layout, although I have tried this same config in Sencha Try and did produce the desired Layout.

Could someone be so kind to point me out to what I might be doing wrong?

Extended info:

I found the following entry in stackoverflow wich pointed to the need of defining a template on the containing element ( [Vbox layout issue in a tab panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757088/vbox-layout-issue-in-a-tab-panel) ) therefore I modified my code of Main.js to add a fit layout to the component containing the eventsCarrousel

```
  Ext.define('EventApp.view.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    id : 'mainView',
    xtype : 'main',
    requires : [ 'Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video' ],
    config : {
        tabBarPosition : 'bottom',

        items : [ {
            title : 'Home',
            iconCls : 'home',
            layout: 'fit', // JUST ADDED THIS LINE
            items : [ {
                docked : 'top',
                xtype : 'titlebar',
                title : 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
            }, {
                xtype : 'eventsCarrousel'
            } ],
        }, 

        {
            title : 'Events',
            iconCls : 'time',
            id : 'eventsButton',

            items : [ {
                docked : 'top',
                xtype : 'titlebar',
                title : 'Events'
            }, {
                xtype : 'eventList',
            } ]
        } 
        ]
    }
});
```

After this change it still did not work when **I tested it using Firefox desktop browser and it works,  but it does not work when using Firefox**.  I thought that it was suposed to be the other way arround since Chrome is a webkit based browser.

This is the output I get in Firefox:

[image]

An this is the exact same code running in Google Chrome.

[image]

My understanding was that the recomended testing browser was Google Chrome because it was based on webkit. Is this correct? Which is the most reliable desktop browser to test sencha touch 2 development in before doing so in the mobile devices?

Thanks

Comment: No one can bring some light so that I can figure out what might be wrong ... The code is currently working correctly in Firefox but it just shows overlapping text when I run it on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer through another question posted in StackOverflow.

Most of my problems were caused by - Chrome 29 bug. See how to fix this here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=90&a=43